# Sum fields created with case when statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with game scores; one row for each mission played. To get the best scores for each user, I created a a query that will give me the maximum score for each mission per user with one row per user. These scores are added as additional columns (mission_1 and mission_2). So far so good.

But now I want to sum the these two fields to get the total max score for each user. However, MySQL won't let me and says Unknown column 'mission_1' in 'field list'.

Is it possible to get these fields summed somehow?

I'm also wondering if it would be possible to get the corresponding row_ids (gsid in my table) for the mission with the maximum score in separate columns (mission_1_id and mission_2_id). But I have a feeling that won't work because I'm using MAX().

```
SELECT m . * , max( m.id ) as max_id, max( submitted_on ) AS max_submitted_on, 
ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =1 THEN score END ) , 0 ) AS mission_1_score, 
ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =2 THEN score END ) , 0 ) AS mission_2_score,
mission_1_score + mission_2_score AS total_score
FROM game_sessions m
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: you can't sum alias, you'll have to sum each of the expresions, let's say ifnull(....mission=1...)+ifnull(....mission=2...)

Comment: thanks, that was the gist of Gordon's answer as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in the same `select` statement.  You either need a subquery or to repeat the expression.

The subquery method:

```
select m.* max_id, max_submitted_on, mission_1_score, mission_2_score,
       mission_1_score + mission_2_score AS total_score
from (SELECT m . * , max( m.id ) as max_id, max( submitted_on ) AS max_submitted_on, 
            ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =1 THEN score END ) , 0 ) AS mission_1_score, 
            ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =2 THEN score END ) , 0 ) AS mission_2_score,
            mission_1_score + mission_2_score AS total_score
      FROM game_sessions m
      GROUP BY username
     ) m
```

Otherwise, change your original `select` statement to:

```
SELECT m . * , max( m.id ) as max_id, max( submitted_on ) AS max_submitted_on, 
       ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =1 THEN score END ) , 0 ) AS mission_1_score, 
       ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =2 THEN score END ) , 0 ) AS mission_2_score,
       (ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =1 THEN score END ) , 0 ) +
        ifnull( max(CASE WHEN mission =2 THEN score END ) , 0 )
       ) AS total_score
```

This seems inelegant, but it is part of the SQL standard.  I think the purpose is to avoid ambiguity in cases such as this:

```
select (a + b) as a, (a + 1) as c
```

What does the `a` in `(a + 1)` refer to?  In the SQL standard, it is unambiguous that it refers to the column in the table.

Comment: Excellent and thank you for the explanation of the why as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
   max(CASE WHEN mission =1 THEN score END )
```